# Show next page for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UICollectionView with paging and it is smaller than the device screen. I would like to show the next page.

I set `self.collectionView.clipsToBounds = NO;` but the next page only shows up when I start scrolling.

Is there a way to *"preload the next page"* and display it.